# Bulk export of data from SQL Server 2008 into XML file (without using BCP)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, export, bcp

I have a requirement whereby I need to refresh databases on Server A with data from Server B (the schemas will always be the same) with subsets of data

Unfortunately, due to the way the servers have been set up and are run (hosted), the option of using BCP **is not available to me**. Also, the servers may not be able to see each other/are linked so a SP on Server B will not be able to access Server A directly.

Because of this, my plan is to run an export procedure on Server A to create a file (XML?) which is placed on to a location available to Server B. I would then create a procedure on Server B to consume the data into the database

My question is: without the use of BCP, what options are available to me for the bulk exporting of data (with selection criteria) from my source server? And does my plan sound sensible? Am I missing any obvious approach/have others solved this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Helo Mike,
have you considered using of SQL Server Integration Services? You could export your data by dynamic SELECT statemenet save them into binary file and transfer them (FTP) to the second locality for loading.